# Requests post json with python

Tags: python, python-requests

my problem is when i'm run the `response.url` from the browser I have the write answer that I'm looking for: `https://www.google.com.ar/?code=TG-MYCODE` but when I do the requests.post from python and try to get response.json() It's broke! (`simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`)

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus

params = {
    'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://www.google.com.ar',
}

url = 'https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?' + urlencode(params, quote_via=quote_plus)

response = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response.url
>>>'https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/login/index?go=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.mercadolibre.com.ar%2Fauthorization%3Fclient_id%3DCLIENT_ID%26response_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com.ar&platform_id=ml&application_id=----'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means when `requests` went to parse a json response, it failed to read the first character, from your example:

```
>>> response.status_code
500

>>> response.text[:16]
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
```

Meaning the website has returned a 500 status, and if you look at the content of the response we can see the webpage returned an html page.

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

`response.json()` sees `<` instead of `{` as the first character.